# Trying to get Selenium to stop the browser during initial load

Tags: python, selenium

trying to figure out how to stop my browser from fully loading (as the content I need is one of the first things to load). In other words, have browser open, wait 3seconds then have the program press stop in browser, so "search_5Hours" can proceed asap.

```
s = Service(r"C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Forex\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
driver.get(LINK)
time.sleep(3) # Doesn't need to be 3 seconds
1. Tried this -> webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
2. Tried this -> driver.execute_script("window.stop()")
3. Tried this -> driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="body").send_keys("Keys.ESCAPE")
search_5Hours = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="5 Hours")
```

Number 3 seems to be the most logical option, eg. stop once body is found (as I presume that to be the first element loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Once you locate the element invoking [`Window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) stops further resource loading in the current browsing context which equivalent to the stop button in the browser.

```
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```